# How to run OpenIE (knowitall project) using sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have referred to the following link: https://github.com/knowitall/openie 
I have downloaded sbt and all required dependencies as mentioned in the above link. But still cannot run OpenIE. My requirement is just running OpenIE tool, be it the new or older version.

While running the commands mentioned in the above link on the terminal 
(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), it gives me the following errors:

[errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9FeJ.png)

Comment: have you seen the repo is deprecated? they recommend you to use https://github.com/allenai/openie-standalone

Comment: also, please, provide the errors as formatted text instead of image

Answer (score 0):

Please use the standalone version; it should work on Scala 2.11. Make sure you `git clone` the repository - there is a [known issue](https://github.com/allenai/openie-standalone/issues/13) with running outside of a git repository.